# File type not recognized when using ffprobe with Python

Tags: python, image-processing, ffmpeg, ffprobe, transport-stream

This is my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os, sys, subprocess, shlex, re
from subprocess import call

def probe_file(filename):
    cmnd = ['ffprobe', '-show_packets', '-show_frames', '-print_format', filename]
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmnd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    print filename
    out, err =  p.communicate()
    print "Output:"
    print out
    if err:
        print "Error:"
        print err

probe_file(sys.argv[1])
```

Being run with this command:

```
python parse_frames_and_packets.py mux_test.ts
```

And I'm getting the following error output:

```
Unknown output format with name 'mux_test.ts'
```

Can you not use .ts file types when using ffprobe with Python? Because I've run ffprobe alone using this exact file and it worked correctly.

Does anyone have any tips?

**Edit:**
it seems to not recognize all types of video, not just transport stream (I just tried it with .avi and got the same response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-print_format` (or the `-of` alias) requires a format. Available formats are: default, compact, csv, flat, ini, json, xml.

Example:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_streams -print_format csv=p=0 input.mkv
```

See the [`ffprobe` documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Writers) for more info.

Comment: I can't believe I missed something so dumb. Thanks so much, you rock!